# What will happen when iOS provisioning profile will expire

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I would like to know what will happen with an app in mdm store or on a device when the provisioning profile will expire. Following provisioning profiles are in my interest: developer, ad-hoc, App Store, entreprise developer, entreprise ad-hoc, entreprise in-house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app that already installed on the devices would not open, it would crash on launch.

App would not be able to install on new devices.

**That apply only for an app that has been distributed outside of Appstore.**

If the app was downloaded from Appstore and you invalidate/expire it's Appstore certificate, nothing would happen to it.

Comment: What will happen with an installed apps if I will delete a provisioning profile in Apple Developer Portal? Why Provisioning Profile has a button "delete" but not "revoke" as it is in case of certificates?

Comment: When it expires the user won't be able to open an app since it is read from app bundle. You could delete it from the portal, nothing would happen since it's already bundled with an app.

Comment: Does an app distributed by Apple via AppStore has a provisioning profile attached to the bundle? If yes then is it the original one, seleced by the developer or a provisioning profile created by Apple once the app was accepted to the AppStore ?

Comment: @abodels if you look closely, you would see that you can't add devices to Appstore certificate, you could add them only to Ad-Hoc and Development one. And yes, on the time of publication of App to the Apple, Apple would resign your app with their own specific certificate.

Comment: I was thinking about a provisioning profile "individual / organization distribution appstore" which doesn't include a white listed devices. So, what happens to this provisioning profile when submitting to the AppStore. The provisioning is recreated by Apple or is the same one which was submitted by the developer?

Comment: @Adobels, unfortunately, I have a very little experience with a corporative app store. From what I know (from working in a big company for a while), we were needed to release a new app with a new certificate once a year otherwise all users would not be able to open an app.